# Uniform continuity of $\sqrt{x^2+x}$

Tags: analysis, continuity

I have to say that I know the definition. I've tried to use is in practical way, but I still don't know how to do that and I don't truly understand that topic.

Please show me step by step solution to that exercise.

Is function uniform continuity:
$$
\sqrt{x^2+x}, x\geq 0
$$

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+2}$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and hence is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$. For $x\in (1,\infty)$ we have $f'(x)=\frac12 \frac{2x+1}{(x^2+x)^{3/2}}$ which is bounded in $(1,\infty)$. Hence $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(1,\infty)$